# Passing button id to function

Tags: jquery, button

I have this html button that I am trying to pass the id to a function

```
<button class= "btn1" id="buttonid1">Set Text</button>
<button class= "btn1" id="buttonid2">Set Text</button>
```

Here is the Javascript to it

```
$(".btn1").click(function(){
    doSomething();                  
    });

function doSomething() {
    goUrl = 'http://www.example/' 
    + $(this).attr('id'); 
    window.location = goUrl;
    }
```

I want the function to redirect the browser to a different website based on button pressed

Comment: `$(this)` is undefined in `doSomething` method. You should pass the button and get id of the button, or pass the id of the button to the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why creating an anonymus function to run a function. Just directly pass the function :

```
$(".btn1").click(doSomething);
```

You don't have to change the `doSomething` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
$(".btn1").click(function(){
    doSomething($(this).attr('id'));                  
});


function doSomething(myId) {
goUrl = 'http://www.example/' 
+ myId; 
window.location = goUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think IDs are heavily abused. You can just pass the button itself:

```
$(".btn1").click(function(){
    doSomething(this);                  
});

function doSomething(button) {
    goUrl = 'http://www.example/' 
    + button.id; 
    window.location = goUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `data-*` attributes to store a id which you wan't to append to your url:

**HTML:**

```
<button class="btn" data-id="1">Button id 1</button>
<button class="btn" data-id="2">Button id 2</button>
```

With your js, you then just read the value of `data-id` and move to that url:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".btn").click(function(){

    // go to url e.g. http://example.com/1
    window.location.href = "http://example.com/" + $(this).data("id");

});
```

Finally, as it seems, your buttons are acting as links (doing navigation) you should consider changing them to links. (a href). Consider this case by case basis. `window.location.href` already simulates similar behavior as clicking a link. You can read more about it from [javascript redirect.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've wrapped `doSomething` within a function, so the context of `this` is no longer your element.

Here is the code, with corrections:

```
$(".btn1").click(doSomething);

function doSomething() {
    goUrl = 'http://www.example/' 
    + $(this).attr('id'); 
    window.location = goUrl;
}
```